# Create relation between tables in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have main table merchants and second table terminals:

Merchant table:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Merchants {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String login;
}
```

Terminal table:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Terminals {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private int merchant_id;

    @Column
    private String mode;
}
```

I want to set merchant_id into table Terminals. I suppose that many to many will be proper relation. How I can create it?

Comment: When you map an entity relationship in JPA, you do so via the *entities*.  You do not map foreign key columns directly.  You can find multiple examples [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+jpa+many+to+many+score%3A5+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: @JohnBollinger can you paste official answer so I can up vote it?

Comment: What is there about the many many JPA documents on the internet that you cant understand?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Join Table:

On Merchants class:

```
 @ManyToMany
 @JoinTable(name="MER_TER", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="MERCH_ID", referencedColumnName="id"),
  inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="TERM_ID", referencedColumnName="id"))
  private List<Terminals> terminalsList;
```

On Terminals class:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="terminalsList")
private List<Merchants> merchantsList;
```

Page of reference: [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany)

If you don't have a Join Table, try to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25018992

Comment: I'm getting  (conn=105) Table 'production.mer_ter' doesn't exist

Comment: I already updated the answer. Sorry but now I'm from smartphone and I can not write code precisely.