# How to map entities B on entities A using a Varchar column on table B?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have some difficulties with a JPA scenario that i'm unable to resolve. I search on Stackoverflow a similar case, but i didn't found.

I only found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244569/what-is-referencedcolumnname-used-for-in-jpa), but it's not exactly my case...

If it already exists, I'm sorry.

Here's my case :

I have two tables :

A :

| id | label | ref_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ARK | Bruce |
| 2 | HAM | Alfred |

B :

| id | name | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bruce | Wayne |
| 2 | Alfred | Pennyworth |
| 3 | Bruce | Banner |

Table B represents a list of persons.
Table A has a label name, and a column to list all persons from Table B that has a particular name.

In Java I have these 2 entities :

```java
public class B {

   private Integer id;

   private String name;

   private String lastname;
}
```

```java
public class A {

   private Integer id;

   private String label;

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinColumn(name="ref_name", referencedColumnName="name")
   private List<B> persons;
}
```

So, I've tried this code, and i have the following error message :

> ERROR: relation "A_persons" does not exist

I can't figure what's wrong with this ...

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

By observing your use of many-to-many mapping, I am guessing you are trying to do many-to-many mapping without the use of a "junction-table". I found this Stackoverflow answer showing how this can be done. What do you think? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25018992

```
public class A {
    private Integer id;
    private String label;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="ref_name",
        referencedColumnName="name")
    private List<B> persons;
}
```

Comment: Hello,
I have the following issue with this : 
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name.

Comment: @Apodeus, are you able to provide the fuller sentence of your error? Like `Unable to find column with logical name: zzz in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(yyy) and its related supertables and secondary tables`, the values `zzz` and `yyy`?